# How to open Launcher with swipe gesture from left side of touchscreen

Tags: 16.04, multi-touch, touchscreen, surface

I have dual booted a Surface Pro 1 with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Generally I have found that touch gestures work well with the exception of one issue - opening the launcher with a touch gesture. I can't open the launcher when it is stowed without resorting to the keyboard. Currently I have the launcher locked in place but I would like it to hide when not in use (as I use on my desktop). Ideally this would involve an intuitive swipe from left gesture.

Is this possible and what steps need I take to implement this?

Comment: I was just now wondering the same thing.  The best solution I've come up with so far is to activate the on-screen keyboard and use that.  It's clear that tablet devices were not a primary target for this UI.